# Spring 3+. Resolve properties by prefix in a placeholder

Tags: java, spring

In my Java class I have a field of type, say, java.util.Properties or java.util.Map.
I'd like Spring to inject the field with all properties which start with the given prefix. Ideally by specifying wildcard in the property annotation, smth like `@Value(${prefix.*})` that doesn't seem to work unfortunately.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Are you trying to read these properties in Spring Boot? If yes, you could use `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="yourPrefix")`

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there isn't a direct way to achieve what you are looking for.

You can however use `Spring EL` in combination with custom implementation of `org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport`.

**First** extend the [PropertiesLoaderSupport](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PropertiesLoaderSupport.html) (*or any of it's subclass*). Introduce a method (*say filterProps*), which will return `java.util.Properties` object with filtered properties, such as below

```
public class CustomPropertyLoader extends PropertiesLoaderSupport {

public Properties filterProperties(String prefix){
    Properties temp = new Properties();

    for(Properties props : this.localProperties){
        /* 
        * Iterate over props and filter them as 
        * per prefix (or any custom logic) to temp
        */
    }
    return temp;
}
```

}

*TIP* - You can use a regex for more generic scenarios instead of `String` as method argument.

**Second** define a corresponding bean of above class

```
<bean id="customPropertyLoader" class="x.y.z.CustomPropertyLoader">
    <property name="locations" value="classpath*:/**/some*.properties"/>
</bean>
```

**Last** annotate the field of type `java.util.Properties` in your class as 
`@Value(#{customPropertyLoader.filterProperties('prefix.*')})`

*P.S.*: Please excuse any compilation / syntax error as I haven't compiled and check the setup; but it should work. In case not, let know in comments.